# In Rails, how do I merge two objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, merge, model, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm running Rails 5.  Let's say I have two objects (of the same type).  How do I merge these objects such that if one contains a null field but the other doesn't, the merged object would have the non-null value?  If both objects have non-nil values for an attribute, an arbitrary one can be selected.  That is, let's say the objects are

```
Object A
    attrA : nil
    attrB : ABCD
    attrC : nil
    attrD : EEE

Object B
    attrA : 1234
    attrB : nil
    attrC : 999
    attrD : FFF
```

How do I write something that merges the object such that the merged object is

```
Object C
    attrA : 1234
    attrB : ABCD
    attrC : 999
    attrD : EEE
```

Comment: If those models are something you created then create your own merge method

Comment: So you're answer to my question is "go create a method that does what you want."  Come on, what kind of an answer is that?

Comment: you didn't provide much details about the objects, are these attributes known or random ? are these bare objects or are they subclasses from another object, like a hash for example

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Object.new(@objectA.attributes.merge(@objectB.attributes) {|_, one, two| one || two})
```

PS. I would suggest to remove `id` field from the model.

Comment: HI, That's a really good suggestion to remove the id attribute.  How do I do that?

Comment: You can filter on the attributes with `select`, i.e. `@objectA.attributes.select { |k,v| k != 'id' }`

Comment: @Dave just assign the new object's `id` field to `nil`.

Comment: Why not `object_a.attributes.except('id')` ?